# How to style divs or li's to look like this progress bar?

Tags: css

I don't know what this is called, so I wasn't able to title this question very well. What I'm wanting to do is make a bar that shows what steps in a process have been completed, like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this kind of effect, and because I don't know what it's called I haven't been able to find any examples or anything.

How can I make something like in the image above?

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/breadcrumb-menu-css3/

Comment: @Amine he asks for progress tracker, not breadcrumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is called `Progress Trackers` , it looks similar to `Breadcrumb` navigation but it has different behavior and uses.

see the following [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/15/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/) to see examples and differences between both.

see the following [tutorial](http://blog.sathomas.me/post/tracking-progress-in-pure-css) to build a progress tracker in pure css.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good place to start with the styling: http://css3button.net/81334

What you're looking at is:

- css gradients for the backgrounds: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/
- **text-shadows** on the text
- **box-shadow** set to inset for the light detail
- and perhaps some pretty advanced **:before** and **:after** styles for the points: 
  http://css-tricks.com/bubble-point-tooltips-with-css3-jquery/